# Change system language for one/active window in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, windows

Is there a posibility to change system language only for one window in WPF?

I know about `InputLanguageManager` but I assume that it changes language in whole system.

Comment: What do you mean by "system" language? The language used to display messages and labels or the language used to parse input? Almost all functions that are affected by the language accept an IFormatProvider parameter which you can use to pass the CultureInfo you want

Comment: Is the meaning of this to change the input Keyboard Layout in your Application?

Comment: It's for me language that's used in whole OS.

Comment: @Smartis , yes I have to change on screen keyboard language for cyrilic (Russia).

Comment: Changing the language for the entire OS is the exaxt opposite of changing the language for a single window

Answer (score 19, accepted):

InputLanguageManager does exactly what you are asking for. It changes the keyboard layout for the current application.

The keyboard layout is kept by the OS for each running application. Eg. if you open Notepad and switch to Russian, the open IE and switch to English, when you activate the Notepad application, your keyboard locale will still be Russian.

The following line changes the keyboard locale just for the current application:

```
InputLanguageManager.Current.CurrentInputLanguage = new CultureInfo("el-GR");
```

The system language (or rather, the system locale) and the keyboard layout are completely different concepts. The keyboard layout is the layout of your keyboard.

There are three different locales used in a .NET application:

- The UI locale is the locale used to display messages and select localized UI strings and layouts. You can change a thread's UI locale by setting its Thread.CurrentUICulture property. Its initial value is governed by the OS's display language in regional settings
- The thread's locale is used to parse strings and convert dates and numerics to string. You can change it by setting the Thread.CurrentCulture property. Its original value is governed by the OS's regional settings Format property
- The system locale is used by non-Unicode applications or when writing to ASCII files and the console.

You can also take advantage of WPF data binding and use InputLanguage as an attached property. In your XAML you can add the InputLanguageManager.InputLanguage property to an element's declaration like this:

```
<TextBox InputLanguageManager.InputLanguage="en-US"></TextBox>
```

You can then bind the property to a property in your code-behind or you ViewModel. Eg.

```
<TextBox InputLanguageManager.InputLanguage="{Binding MyLanguageInfo}"></TextBox>
```

Setting this property to a specific value will cause the keyboard of the UI element to change:

```
MyLanguageInfo = new CultureInfo("en-US");
```

or

```
MyLanguageInfo = new CultureInfo("el-GR");
```

You can go further with this and bind the InputLanguage property other elements, eg. a listbox of language options

Comment: hey dude, can you give me a full example of this implement?

Comment: Thank you. This works pefectly for setting input to a specific language for a specific framwework element such as a TextBox in WPF.

Answer (score 3):

For Keyboard Layout Changing are you `InputLanguageManager` on the right way.

```
InputLanguageManager.SetInputLanguage(this,CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("ru"));
```

---

With the first Parameter of the `SetInputLanguage()` methode you set the `DependencyObject` which is the target of your Keyboard Layout.

Comment: InputLanguage is a Windows Forms class, not a WPF class

Comment: Ok, but what if user doesn't have russian language in system?

Comment: Then you have to install it on the Windows System.

Comment: SetInputLanguage shouldn't be used directly in code. It's there to support the InputLanguage attached property

Comment: There is no need to "install" a keyboard layout in Windows Vista and above, just go to the language bar, Settings and select the additinal keyboard. .NET uses Unicode already so russian text will display correctly no matter how you enter it

Comment: That's about the display languages and system messages, NOT the keyboard layouts or the Unicode fonts. Just go to the language bar, right click on the language icon, select Settings and click Add in the General settings tab. Or go to Control Panel> Region and Language > Keyboards and Languages and click "Change Keyboards"